# Unable to connect to Cloudfront from MacOSX client

Tags: c++, macos, libcurl, amazon-cloudfront

My multi-platform client, written in `C++` and built on `cURL`, should download a file from Cloudfront. On Windows, the download works fine with `libcurl 7.40.0` and `OpenSSL 1.0.2c`. On MacOSX:

- the file served via "direct" Amazon AWS link is correctly downloaded;
- the file served via Cloudfront link cannot be downloaded: CURL error after the call is set to `CURLE_SSL_CONNECT_ERROR`, and debug informations show that the protocol breaks during SSL handshake.

The file is correctly downloaded also via `curl` command from MacOSX bash (version 7.54.0).

I am linking against the `cURL` version installed on my iMac (version `7.54.0` with security layer provided by `zlib` version `1.2.8`). The version supports SSL and `TLSv1.2` (as can be seen when performing AWS download).

I am at my wit's end: `TLSv1.2` is supported and should be enabled during communication with Cloudfront. Is there something else that I forgot?

Thank you in advance for your help. MWE and responses from both servers follow.

---

Minimum working example (urls faked):

```
#include "curl/curl.h"

#define URLDOWNLOAD "https://x.cloudfront.net/file.file?Expires=123&Signature=456&Key-Pair-Id=789"
#define AWSURLDOWNLOAD "https://x.amazonaws.net/file.file?Expires=123&Signature=456&Key-Pair-Id=789"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

    CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE, true);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPIDLE, 30);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPINTVL, 5);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_RANGE, "0-");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPINTVL, 2);

    // with URLDOWNLOAD the call fails. With AWSURLDOWNLOAD the call is successful.
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, URLDOWNLOAD);

    CURLcode error = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    curl_easy_reset(curl);

    return 0;
}
```

---

The debug informations when downloading from AWS:

```
*   Trying ip...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to x.amazonaws.com (ip) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* Server certificate: *.x.amazonaws.com
* Server certificate: DigiCert Baltimore CA-2 G2
* Server certificate: Baltimore CyberTrust Root
> GET /FILE?X-Amz-Expires=431861&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AQ/20170814/aws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20170814T090903Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=0eb HTTP/1.1
Host: x.amazonaws.com
Range: bytes=0-100
Accept: */*

< HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
< x-amz-id-2: Q/0/xjrH4tNKcJU=
< x-amz-request-id: 92CEA7A5E6AB
< Date: Mon, 14 Aug 2017 14:32:46 GMT
< Last-Modified: Tue, 16 May 2017 22:15:57 GMT
< ETag: "9d57e32d88c89a-55"
< x-amz-meta-cb-modifiedtime: Tue, 16 May 2017 22:13:27 GMT
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Range: bytes 0-100/566567658
< Content-Type: application/octet-stream
< Content-Length: 101
< Server: AmazonS3
<
\246ՙ\30\363\360т.C\375\205\211\327\327\343\204\320\224\3404\327dͩ\3362\\306\354%%\214}"\3171\216\362}La\245U\304}\260\223\205\332\335 ]\314\330\300
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #0 to host x.amazonaws.com left intact
```

---

The debug informations when downloading from Cloudfront:

```
*   Trying ip...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to x.cloudfront.net (ip) port 443 (#0)
* SSL peer handshake failed, the server most likely requires a client certificate to connect
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 1
* Closing connection 0
```

The two calls are made with the exact same linked library

Comment: Can you check the DNS settings on both of the cloud and AWS? See any difference?

Comment: Also have a look at [this](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=723195)